# How to get multiple custom objects from joined query in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-2

I recently learned that in Codeigniter, when getting results from a query, using `result()` or `row()` you can add a string parameter to cast the results to a custom object.

So, I have these two tables:

```
Books
id
title
author_id

Authors
id
name
```

And this query:

```
$this->db->select('b.id, b.title, a.name AS author_name');
$this->db->from('books AS b');
$this->db->join('authors AS a', 'b.author_id = a.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
$books = $query->result('Book');
```

`$books` is now an array of Book objects (I have a `Book class` loaded), so I can do this:

```
foreach($books as $book) {
    echo $book->title;
    echo $book->author_name;
}
```

Of course, `author_name` is a field of `$book`. For this very simple case is fine, but imagining a more complex situations, with more tables, more classes, and more fields involved, it would be nice if I could create a `$author` object directly in the query, to have something like this:

```
foreach($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->name;
}
```

One solution I've found around is to have something like this in the Book class:

```
class Book {

    public function author()
    {
        if (empty($this->author)) {
            $ci =& get_instance();
            $this->author = $ci->db->get_where('authors',
                ['id' => $this->author_id])->row(0, 'Author');
        }

        return $this->author;
    }
}
```

Which works, but this means that after the original query with the join, I will do other n queries to get the authors. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

For any given books, you will always have to perform multiple requests to get different objects. You are able to get basic, essential, information in a single query though.

In a more complex case, such as with the author, you could either have a field "authorId" and "authorName" in your book, and a "getAuthor" method.
Your SQL query could then populate the author name and id in your book object with a single query, and the book could load the complex author object if needed.

Comment: but this is basically what I'm doing in the Book class with the `author()` function, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is a bad practice because you're mixing a lot of code inside an entity. On the other hand, there isn't any automatic way to create an object within another. To do that "automatically" you have to use an ORM such Doctrine.

On the other hand, with your example, you should move the logic code from Book to the model class ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)) to  [separate the concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98765/1628790).

One example could be:

```
public function getBook($id)
{
    $book = $this->db->get_where('books', ['id' => $id])->row(0, 'Book');
    $boo->author = $this->db->get_where('authors', ['id' => $book->author_id])->row(0, 'Author');
}
```

Or, you could use a Closure to encapsulate everything and defer the instantiation:

```
public function getBook($id)
{
    $book = $this->db->get_where('books', ['id' => $id])->row(0, 'Book');
    $book->authorClosure = $this->getAuthorClosure();
}

public function getAuthorClosure(Book $book)
{
    $db = $this->db;
    return function() use ($book , $db) {
        return $db->get_where('authors', ['id' => $book->author_id])->row(0, 'Author');
    };
}

public function getAuthor()
{
    if (!isset($this->author))
    {
        $closure = $this->authorClosure;
        $this->author = $closure();
    }

    return $this->author;
}
```

But with a closure, you should have a method to return the author and not a public variable.

Comment: maybe it's not clear from my example, but the query is in a Book_model and then I have a Book class. The foreach and echo part was just a use example

Comment: @Carlo On your example, the `author` is inside a class called `Book` which seems an entity

Comment: I can call that function getAuthour(). Would that be ok? I guess it's fine for an Book object to have a method to retrieve its author, or not?

Comment: The method is ok, but that `$ci =& get_instance();` and that `$this->author = $ci->db->get_where('authors', ['id' => $this->author_id])->row(0, 'Author');` is awful by its own reasons. So much knowledgement for an entity

Comment: That's why I suggest the use of a closure. You can separate the logic of retrieve the author and inject inside the Book object. Book object doesn't know anything more than necessary.